# MVC4 get list of checkboxes in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of checkboxes generated in the View using the following code:

```
                using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateItems", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
                    foreach (myProject.Models.item t in ViewBag.Items)
                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.CheckBox("chkT", t.selected, new { id = "chkT" + t.id })
                            @Html.Label(t.description)
                        </div>
                    }
                    <button type="submit" class="mfButton" value="SaveItemss">Save Changes</button>
                }
```

What I need to is to be able to get the values of these generated checkboxes in the controller. So far I have the following:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateItemss(List<bool> chkT)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

However this being a boolean only give me true or false and the id of the values to which they belong. Is there a way get the name/value pair?

Thanks

Comment: You can pass the `FormCollection` as parameter, it will hold all your checkboxes.

Comment: or Request.Form["CheckBoxName"] which will give a list of all checked checkboxes

Comment: what name/value pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using ViewBag, I would use strongly typed view. I would create a model and add the lists as property. My Models should look like:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}


public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I am passing the model with dummy data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Test model = new Test()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Selected = false, Description = "Item1"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Selected = false, Description = "Item2"},
            new Item {Id = 3, Selected = false, Description = "Item3"}
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

In my View I am using for loop to generate list of Items:

```
@model MVCTest.Models.Test

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateItems", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {

    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Items[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Items[i].Selected, new {id = "checkbox_" + i} )
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Items[i].Description)
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" class="mfButton" value="SaveItemss">Save Changes</button>
}
```

In the controller I am catching the posted model and find all Items inside its Items property:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItems(Test model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            // You can access model.Items here
            //Do whatever you need
        }

    return View(model);
}
```

I would suggest to read this blog: [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Comment: Yeah I think this is the best solution, was just trying to be lazy really.